# Custom Layout, losing custom defined attributes in attrs.xml

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, merge

I have the following in attrs.xml

```
  <declare-styleable name="ToolsView">
        <attr name="width_behaviour" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

I have the following code in my layout file:

```
  <com.hidden.hidden2.view.ToolsView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/com.hidden.hidden2"
        android:id="@+id/page_toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/tools_background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layerType="software"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:width_behaviour="@integer/tools_view_width_behaviour" />
```

However, when I try to read app:width_behaviour in the constructor of my class

```
if (attributeSet != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.ToolsView, 0, 0);
            final int N = a.getIndexCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                int attr = a.getIndex(i);
                switch (attr) {
                case R.styleable.ToolsView_width_behaviour:
                    widthBehaviour = a.getInteger(attr, -1);
                    break;
                }
            }

            a.recycle();
```

The attributes set is not null, but N is 0 - no custom attributes are obtained! So it never gets inside the for loop.

Any idea why is that? I used to this to a lot of layouts, for the first time I am having issues.

Answer (score 1):

Change attribute's format to integer or dimension (depends on what you mean under width_behaviour) and it should work. References are for another purpose.

Comment: It still not wokrs? hhh... What is getContext? Why dont you use context from construstor param?

Comment: The super constructor was already executed, so technically I can take it from getContext() of the view. I am not getting it directly because this is in an initializer method defined right after the super(context, attrs) call. Anyways, I found the error, see my answer below.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that you fixed it )

Answer (score 0):

Ouch. This was a rather dumb mistake.

See the definition of xmlns:app -  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/com.hidden.hidden2"
It should be xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.hidden.hidden2"

The /apk/res/ part was somehow missing in my declaration.

Hope this helps someone someday.